# Стоит ли обособлять «по сути»?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова, невыделение-вводных

> Музей, это изобретение новейшего времени, и **занят-то по сути именно
>   тем**, что изымает вещи из человеческого обихода, лишает их
>   первоначальных функций: ведь если на стул нельзя сесть – значит, это
>   уже не стул. И если перед этим распятием нельзя больше обращаться к
>   Богу, значит, это не распятие…

Comment: Галина, а почему после "музея" запятая? Не забудьте ответить, пожалуйста.

Comment: Тёмыч, я  ж правил не знаю: как объясню-то? Могу только на пальцах: не музей - это изобретение (подлежащее - сказуемое), а музей=изобретение (уточнение).

Comment: Тогда непонятен смысл И. Если бы было тире и сказуемые, разделённые И, было бы понятно. Ещё у И может быть смысл "как раз (и)", но разве тут может быть в этом смысле?

Comment: Могу построить параллельную констракшен: Васька Пупкин, этот идиот в квадрате, и прийти-то не смог вовремя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***По сути*** здесь наречие (наречное выражение), имеет прямое значение исходного существительного СУТЬ, самое главное и существенное в ком-, чём-л.; сущность.

Интонационно не выделяется, вписывается в структуру предложения.

Answer (score 3):

> [ПО СУТИ (ДЕЛА), вводное слово](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_605)
>   То же, что «в сущности говоря». Подробно о пунктуации при вводных словах и сочетаниях см. в Прил. 2.
>   ...Это куда как реальней, чем этот асфальт, которого, по сути, нет. В. Пелевин, Чапаев и Пустота. По сути дела, мне совершенно незачем было оставаться в редакции. М. Булгаков, Мне приснился сон.
>   ! Не смешивать с употреблением в роли членов предложения ( в знач. «по самому главному, существенному вопросу; в целом»).
>   Художественное произведение должно быть абсолютно законченным объектом и по форме и по сути… Ч. Айтматов, И дольше века длится день.

Я бы добавил слово *он* и поставил 2 запятые:

**Музей, это изобретение новейшего времени, и занят-то он, по сути, именно тем, что ...**

Сравните: *Музей по своей сути — организация, которая занята тем, что ...*

Comment: Sharon права, imho.